# Row space and column space

Tags: linear-algebra

We know that the column-rank of an arbitrary matrix is equal to it's row-rank.
But what are possible interpretations of this equation or equality ?
How can we visualize this equation intuitively?

Answer (score 1):

For every leading entry we have a non-zero row in reduced form of the matrix. Every leading entry corresponds to a column that has been transformed to an elementary vector. The two numbers coincide.

Answer (score 0):

Take a 2x2 matrix

[a, b; na, nb]

clearly you have two columns, [a, na] and [b, nb]. There is a common factor a and b resp.

Otherwise, you have [a, b] and [na, nb]. Necessarily a common factor 1, n exists resp.